# Are ergonomics questions appropriate on UX?

Tags: discussion

I have a number of questions about ergonomics related to computer/laptop use, including what title an ergonomics expert has, because maybe what I actually want is a consultant - my interest is strongly health-related though, so is this the appropriate Stack?

(My other thought was to do some retail research and post lots of product claims to Skeptics :D)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some links between ergonomics and UX design, especially if it is related to hardware devices and user interface design that relate to movement (repetitive) and ease of use. If you can frame the question so that it addresses specific issues about how the usage might lead to a better user experience then it may be appropriate.

Comment: thanks michael, do you know of a stack more generally applicable to ergo questions? (I couldn't find one)

Comment: @d3vid The closest thing I could find to an ergonomics site was this proposal for a general medicine site. If you propose some ergonomics questions you can get a feel for how they might be received there: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45132/medicine

Comment: You can also try the workplace exchange, since some of the things that you want to ask will also be specific for the home/office environment?

Comment: it appears that ergo questions are definitely valid on workplace SE http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics but medicine sounds good too, I guess it's one of those multistack topics :)

Comment: also personal productivity SE http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics

Answer (score 5):

My position is that ergonomic questions are relevant for UX.se, but as with all questions the topic alone doesn't determine their suitability.

If you were to post product claims to skeptics (as I understand the point), it would amount to a 'lets review this' question.  And since reviews aren't allowed, it would outside the bounds of UX.se.